# Find the max integer value of string numbers in DB2

Tags: string, db2

I have a table that contains a particular column filled with numeric values, but they are strings. So the number 99 is actually maintianed as '99'. How would I go about finding the max value of this column? If I use the standard MAX() function, like this:

```
Select Max(Column)
from table
```

I only get the lexigraphical (I think) max. So, if '99' and '888' are in the column, '99' is returned. Is there a simple way of getting back the max integer value?

Comment: So, I didn't set this DB up, but I am stuck with the problem. I came here looking for help, and I am glad to see someone did respond with something to try.

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(int(column)) from table
```

or pad as a string to the column length (assuming the length is 10):

```
select max(lpad(column, 10, '0') from table
```

Comment: I tried both of these and ran into an issue with each. For the first, I am getting an invalid character found in character string arguement of the function "SYSIBM.INTEGER". Would that be due to an invalid character in one of the strings?

For the second, I am getting '9999' returned, when I know there is a '20000' entry. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested the lpad approach - in case there are non-digits in the column.  Make sure your padding length (2nd number) is wide enough.  You could test the padding with something like: `select lpad(column, 10, '0') from table fetch first 100 rows only`

Comment: The column width is less than 10, so that should be long enough. I wound up using a case statement that checked to see if the field UPPER and LOWER were the same then cast it as an integer and took that value. I just couldn't get the lpad to give me usable results. Thanks for responding though.